# Tomcat 7 replication - different machines

Tags: session, tomcat, session-replication

I have 2 tomcats:

1) 10.0.50.35

2) 10.0.110.31

10.0.50.35 server.xml:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

 <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
             channelSendOptions="8">

      <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
               expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
               notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

      <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                    address="228.0.0.4"
                    port="45564"
                    frequency="500"
                    dropTime="3000"/>
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                  address="auto"
                  port="4000"
                  autoBind="100"
                  selectorTimeout="5000"
                  maxThreads="6"/>

        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
          <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
        </Sender>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
      </Channel>

      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
             filter=""/>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

      <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                watchEnabled="false"/>

      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
    </Cluster>
```

And here is the 10.0.110.31 server.xml

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

 <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
             channelSendOptions="8">

      <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
               expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
               notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

      <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                    address="228.0.0.4"
            bind="10.0.50.35"
                    port="45564"
                    frequency="500"
                    dropTime="3000"/>
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                  address="auto"
                  port="4000"
                  autoBind="100"
                  selectorTimeout="5000"
                  maxThreads="6"/>

        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
          <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
        </Sender>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
      </Channel>

      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
             filter=""/>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

      <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                watchEnabled="false"/>

      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
    </Cluster>
```

10.0.110.31 starts up, but the 10.0.50.35 doesnt, with the following error:

```
SEVERE: Unable to start cluster.
org.apache.catalina.tribes.ChannelException: java.net.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address; No faulty members identified.
at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelCoordinator.internalStart(ChannelCoordinator.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelCoordinator.start(ChannelCoordinator.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.start(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatchInterceptor.start(MessageDispatchInterceptor.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.start(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.start(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel.start(GroupChannel.java:419)
at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster.startInternal(SimpleTcpCluster.java:685)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
```

Comment: I know nothing about clustering Tomcat, but should there be a bind="10.0.110.31" entry for your 10.0.50.35 server?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the "auto" from

```
<Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                  address="auto"
                  port="4000"
                  autoBind="100"
                  selectorTimeout="5000"
                  maxThreads="6"/>
```

and put your lan address.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

First, make sure multicast is [properly enabled on your system](http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2009/11/08/enabling-multicast-on-your-macos-unix/).

Second, make sure your JVM tries to bind to an IPv4 address first (not an IPv6 one). Do that by adding the following to JAVA_OPTS in catalina.sh in the tomcat's bin directory:

`JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"`